# Problemas con funcion excel laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un modulo, en donde puedo consultar información por filtros, y una vez consultados en la parte de abajo, al dar clic en el botón Descargar excel, este me genera un excel con lo ultimo que consulte, esto funciona perfecto cuando lo trabajo en mi servidor local, ahora, este proyecto ya lo subí a un hosting publico, todo funciona bien a excepción de este modulo, ya que al filtrar por ejemplo gobernadorcuatro, este me genera el excel con ese filtro, pero si busco gobernadortres, al descargar el excel, este me genera el mismo excel con la información de gobernadorcuatro, cuando debería ser gobernador tres.
Esto pasa en google chrome y mozilla, por que en opera si funciona bien, pero no se por que.

Este es el codigo html

```html
@extends('layouts.layout') @section('content')
<div class="row">
    <section class="content">
        <!-- <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" > -->
        <table style="width:95%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" border="0.1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @if(Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        {{Session::get('success')}}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h3>Numero de usuarios: {{ $conteo }}</h3>

                            <!-- panel de busqueda -->
                            <br>

                            <table style="width:97%">

                                <tr style="font-family:arial; font-size:19px; font-weight:bold; color:#2a88bd">
                                    <td> Estado</td>
                                    <td> Referido </td>
                                    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
                                    <td> Informe</td>
                                </tr>
                                @endif @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('gestion'))
                                <td> Informe</td>
                                @endif
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width:20%;" border="0">

                    <form action="{{route('usuario.bestado')}}" method="get">

                        <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:40%;" border="0">
                                    <select name="valorestado" id="valorestado" class=" form-control" required>
                                        <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                                        <option value="Descartado">Descartado</option>
                                        <option value="Confirmado">Confirmado</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width:50%;" border="1">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </td>
                </td>

                <td style="width:20%;" border="0">
                    <form action="{{route('usuario.selectord')}}" method="get">

                        <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:50%;" border="0">

                                    <select name="valorusuario" id="valorusuario" class=" form-control" required>
                                        @foreach($usuariosOpciones as $user_id => $usuario_ad)
                                        <option value="{{ $user_id }}">{{ $usuario_ad }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </td>

                                <td style="width:50%;" border="1">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <td style="width:20%;" border="0">

                            @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
                            <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:50%;" border="0">
                                        <a href="{{ route('products.excelgobernadores') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                         Descargar reporte en Excel
                      </a>
                                        <td style="width:25%;" border="0">
                            </table>
                            @endif @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('gestion'))
                            <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:50%;" border="0">
                                        <a href="{{ route('products.excelgobernadores') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                         Descargar reporte en Excel
                      </a>
                                        <td style="width:25%;" border="0">
                            </table>
                            @endif

                            </td>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                    <table style="width:100%;  border-spacing:10px">

                        <tr style="font-family:arial; font-size:19px; font-weight:bold; color:#2a88bd">
                            <td> Gobernacion</td>
                            <td> Alcaldia </td>
                            <td> Concejo</td>
                            <td> Diputado</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:20%;" border="0">

                                <form action="{{route('usuario.governor')}}" method="get">
                                    <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="0">

                                                <select name="governore" id="governore" class=" form-control" required>
                                                    @foreach($governor as $gove)
                                                    <option value="{{ $gove->idg }}">{{ $gove->governor_candidate }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="1">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <td style="width:20%;" border="0">

                                <form action="{{route('usuario.mayor')}}" method="get">
                                    <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="0">

                                                <select name="mayore" id="mayore" class=" form-control" required>
                                                    @foreach($mayor as $mayo)
                                                    <option value="{{ $mayo->idm }}">{{ $mayo->mayor_candidate }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="1">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <td style="width:20%;" border="0">

                                <form action="{{route('usuario.advice')}}" method="get">
                                    <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="0">

                                                <select name="advicee" id="advicee" class=" form-control" required>
                                                    @foreach($advice as $advi)
                                                    <option value="{{ $advi->ida }}">{{ $advi->advice_candidate }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="1">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <td style="width:20%;" border="0">

                                <form action="{{route('usuario.assembly')}}" method="get">
                                    <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="0">

                                                <select name="assemblye" id="assemblye" class=" form-control" required>
                                                    @foreach($assembly as $asse)
                                                    <option value="{{ $asse->idas }}">{{ $asse->assembly_candidate }}</option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="width:40%;" border="1">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enviar</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                    <br>
                    <!-- FIN panel de busqueda -->

                    <div class="table-container">
                        <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Usuario_ad</th>
                                <th>Gestion</th>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellido</th>
                                <th>Cedula</th>
                                <th>Telefonos</th>
                                <th>Direccion</th>
                                <th>barrio</th>
                                <th>Lugar_v</th>
                                <th>Mesa_v</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Ciudad</th>
                                <th>Comentario</th>
                                <th>Gobernador</th>
                                <th>Alcalde</th>
                                <th>Consejo</th>
                                <th>Asamblea</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                @endif @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('gestion'))
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                @endif
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @if($consultarea->count()) @foreach($consultarea as $usuario)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->usuario_ad}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->asignacion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->nombre}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->apellido}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->cedula}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->telefonos}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->direccion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->barrio}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->lugar_votacion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->mesa_votacion}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->email}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->ciudad}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->comentario}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->governor_candidate}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->mayor_candidate}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->advice_candidate}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->assembly_candidate}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$usuario->estado}}</td>

                                    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="{{action('CuentaController@cestado')}}" method="post">
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                            <select name="confirmar" id="confirmar" class=" form-control" required>
                                                <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                                                <option value="Descartado">Descartado</option>
                                                <option value="Confirmado">Confirmado</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <input type="text" name="idestado" id="idestado" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuario->id}}" readonly="readonly" style="visibility:hidden">
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><span>Revisar</span></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    @endif @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('gestion'))
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="{{action('CuentaController@cestado')}}" method="post">
                                            {{csrf_field()}}
                                            <select name="confirmar" id="confirmar" class=" form-control" required>
                                                <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                                                <option value="Descartado">Descartado</option>
                                                <option value="Confirmado">Confirmado</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <input type="text" name="idestado" id="idestado" class="form-control input-sm" value="{{$usuario->id}}" readonly="readonly" style="visibility:hidden">
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><span>Revisar</span></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                    @endif

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach @else
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="8">No hay registro !!</td>
                                </tr>
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    {{ $consultarea->links() }}
                    </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </div>
</div>
</section>

@endsection
```

el metodo al que llamo es products.excelgobernadores en el rol admin, ahora este es el metodo.

```html
public function excelgobernadores(Request $request)
    {        
       
       $registrado = \Auth::user()->tipos_usuarios_id;
       $filtros = \Auth::user()->username;
       

       if($registrado == 1)

        {

          $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);


            $urlgover = request()->headers->get('referer');
             parse_str(parse_url($urlgover)['query'], $output);
              $valorgober = $output['governore'];

    
            Excel::create('ExcelGobernadores', function($excelgobernadores) use ($valorgober){
                $excelgobernadores->sheet('Excelsheet', function($sheet) use ($valorgober){
        
                  $conteogobe = usuarios::join('governor', 'usuarios.gobe_id', '=' , 'governor.idg')->where('gobe_id',$valorgober)->where('asignacion', '<>', '')->select('user_id', 'user_id', 'usuario_ad', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'cedula', 'telefonos', 'direccion', 'barrio', 'lugar_votacion', 'mesa_votacion', 'email', 'ciudad', 'comentario', 'asignacion', 'estado', 'governor.governor_candidate')->get();
                  $conteogobe = json_decode( json_encode($conteogobe), true);
                  $sheet->fromArray($conteogobe);
                  $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');

               });

            })->export('xls');
        
       }
```

Acaso debe tener en cuenta algo en el hosting para que esto no ocurra, o hay algo que se me ha pasado por alto? o debo reinstalar la libreria en el hosting o revisar extensiones?  uso esta libreria en el controlador use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;